# Connecting to a Google Cloud MySQL database in AppEngine(Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've had a lot of issues with this and found multiple different types of syntax to do this, and so far none of them seem to work.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine 
based on this tutorial from google it seems that sqlalchemy is
 the best tool to use, which I've never up until now.

I followed all the other instructions but I can't figure out where 
/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME is listed.
I presume the socket it's referring to is the instance connection page on the SQL overview page. Mine looks something like MYPROJECT:us-east1:MYSQLINSTANCE.
I also saw some documentation that had the SQL Instance swapped out with the database name, so I tried that as well with no luck.

Right now my Python connection string looks like

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
unix_socket=/cloudsql/MYPROJECT:us-east1:MYSQLINSTANCE
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='mysql+pymysql',
        username=MYUSERNAME,
        password=MYPASSWORD,
        database=MYDATABASE,
        query={
            'unix_socket': '/cloudsql/{}'.format('MYPROJECT:us-east1:MYSQLINSTANCE')
        }
    ),
    pool_size=10,
    max_overflow=2,
    pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
    pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
)
```

And right now it's telling me that it can't connect to the SQL instance on localhost, even though I'm clearly not trying to connect on localhost.
I tried connecting with environment variables defined in the App.YAML as defined in the tutorial, and also modified the App.YAML based on a couple different versions of the Syntax I've found online but no combination actually seems to work. So right now I'm just plugging the variables directly into my main.py, which I'm aware is less secure.

I also tried doing the connection URL as a long URL like

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    unix_socket=/cloudsql/MYPROJECT:us-east1:MYSQLINSTANCE
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<MYPROJECT>:us-east1:<MYSQLINSTANCE>
        ),
        pool_size=10,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
        pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
    )
```

and that gives me a weirder error that looks like
Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql://(that URL I entered up there)

I also looked into connecting via the public IP Address listed on the SQL page, but that requires whitelisting a connection, and I'm not sure what IP the Appengine App would be connecting from. Regardless, I'm not sure what the best way to do this is at this point, and any help making this connection would be greatly appreciated. I'm just banging my head against a wall at this point.

Answer (score 0):

First - the `<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_STRING>` is in the format `<project>:<region>:<instance>` and is found on the "overview" page for your Cloud SQL instance (right next to the IP).

Second - the socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_STRING>` is automatically available for your when running in App Engine standard. When running locally, you'll need to provide your own. You can connect via IP instead, or you can use the [cloudsql-proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy#running-locally) to create one at the same place the App Engine one is located.

In order for the App Engine connection to work, you need to do a few things - First, make sure you have the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled. Next, you need to make sure the IAM account you are using to connect with has the `Cloud SQL Connect` role. Go to the IAM page and make sure the service account has the correct permissions (if you aren't using your own, App Engine has a default service account).

The reason the error complains about 'localhost' is because pymysql is using the default host for the error, even though a unix socket is being used to attempt connection.

Comment: I have the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled and the appengine default service account has the correct permissions, but I'm still running into errors. What should my Python string to connect to the instance actually look like?